# Unbind all tmux prefix key

Tags: regex, bash, awk, zsh, tmux

How can unbind default prefix key in tmux?

- I mean the default set by the user, Not necessarily C-b
- I do not know what the user has set! So I have to discover the prefix with the command
- solution should be in the zsh file and not in .tmux.conf
- use `tmux` command takes precedence over Regex

for getting default prefix key I use

```sh
$ tmux send-prefix
^[w
```

when I pipe `send-prefix` output to `tmux unbind` command, the output is as follows

```
$ tmux send-prefix | xargs tmux unbind
^[`missing key
```

if the command return `M-q`, I can unbind as following (but not return)

```
a_command | xargs tmux unbind
```

Other way is to use Regex for following output (but how?)

```sh
$ tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix
bind-key    -T prefix       M-q                  send-prefix
```

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by using `awk`!

### unbind prefix key

```sh
$ tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix 
bind-key    -T prefix       M-q                  send-prefix

$ tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix | awk '{print $4}'
M-q

$ tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix | awk '{print $4}' | xargs tmux unbind
```

### unbind prefix2 key

```sh
$ tmux show-options -g | grep prefix2
prefix2 M-t

$ tmux show-options -g | grep prefix2 | awk '{print $2}'
M-t

$ tmux show-options -g | grep prefix2 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs tmux unbind
```

if have multi output we can iterate by piping to while

```sh
tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix | awk '{print $4}' |  while prefix_key line; do
    tmux unbind $prefix_key
done
```

(Similarly for prefix2)

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the .tmux.conf:

```
# remap prefix from CTRL-B to CTRL+Spacebar                                                                                                           
set -g prefix C-Space                                                                                                                                     
unbind C-b
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not know what the user has set! So I have to discover the prefix with the command

Comment: @njfamirm Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood the Q (+1 for the edits to make the Q clearer)